# Why does my clothes dryer make noise and stop before the cycle ends?

Tags: dryer, electric-motor

I inherited a Kenmore 80 Series gas dryer from the previous owners of my house. If I put it on a timed dry cycle for 80 minutes, it usually stops before the 80 minutes are up. Sometimes, when I press the start button, it refuses altogether to stop, just buzzing while the button is depressed. When it runs, it sounds to me like it's making a disturbing scraping sound, though I'm not sure if that's normal or a recent development.

I took out the drum and tried turning the motor by hand. It turns, and makes a squeaking sound as it turns.

- What could be causing these symptoms?
- Does replacing the motor seem like a worthwhile step?
- What other diagnostics should I do?

Comment: The motor itself squeaks? I'd be hesitant to get that far into parts replacement when a "whole 'new' used dryer" will typically cost less.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/130043/deteriorations-in-rear-of-gas-dryer We got rid of this dryer soon after.

Answer (score 1):

Check the rollers and other components. It should turn smoothly, not necessarily easy but it should not make a scraping sound. There is something rubbing against the drum, broken roller wheel, etc.

If the drum is rubbing and creating more friction than it should, then the motor will overheat and trip its internal thermal protection. That is why it will run for a short period and then stop. When it cools down you can start it again.

Check YouTube for some videos on how to open up the case. It is pretty easy actually.

I have a similar Kenmore and it is 30 years old and still working. Just had to replace the belt for the first time. So, they will last a lifetime if you pull some maintenance on them once in a while.

Comment: I've got it open and mostly disassembled. YouTube was indeed my friend. The wheels look fine. Based on what I wrote, it doesn't sound like a motor problem to you? Does your answer change when seeing the pics [here](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/130043)?

Comment: I have an electric Maytag dryer that became balky because the connection to the humidity sensor in the drum, was though a brush that would wear out or lose contact.  It would have to be adjusted or replaced from time to time.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Do the wheels roll easily? The last set I replaced "looked" OK but did not turn nearly as well as the replacements did. Scraping may also be a failed/failing/missing drum gasket (seal, whatever they call it, which may vary) which is a (usually) felt strip between the edges of the rotating drum and the fixed front and/or rear of the dryer frame. Neither of these would seem to have anything to do with "not stopping when asked to stop." Unless you actually meant not starting when asked to start? If so, edit the question...