# Deteriorations in rear of gas dryer

Tags: dryer, corrosion

I opened up the rear of my Kenmore 80 Series gas dryer and discovered the following aspects of deterioration:

1. Corrosion near the bottom of the heater box. See photos 1 and 2.
2. Crumbling of the foam around the edges of the two large holes in the lint assembly. See photos 3 - 6.

With respect to each of these:

- How concerned should I be?
- Should I do anything to correct the symptom?
- Should I do anything to prevent this from happening?

1: Heater box corrosion
[image: Heater box corrosion]

2: Heater box corrosion, detail
[image: Heater box corrosion, detail]

3: Lint assembly top hole
[image: Lint assembly top hole]

4: Lint assembly bottom hole
[image: Lint assembly bottom hole]

5: Vent where the lint assembly top hole goes
[image: Vent where the lint assembly top hole goes]

6: Fan where the lint assembly bottom hole goes
[image: Fan where the lint assembly bottom hole goes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the natural gas burns it blasts onto that surface of the duct work we can see that is burned through. The metal is disintegrating from the concentrated heat. Your dryer is operating in an unsafe condition.  You are probably not getting a proper burn of your gas and could be making some CO. This is a hazardous condition.  It is time to get rid of this machine and get a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Given the burn through we can see on the air duct, it is time to retire this baby. I would say that this baby has dried all the clothes it should be required to dry.

Comment: Can you explain more? What's wrong with it?